# Send mail to everyone in your SQL table with PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I wanna send a mail to  each email address in my SQL table. I have tried with $mail['email']but that was not the key. Must i do a foreach?

When I manually fill in an email address, i receive the mail.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['knop'])){
    include 'Db.php';
    include 'connect.php';
    include 'functions.php';
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO post (subject, onderwerp1, nieuw1, onderwerp2, nieuw2, onderwerp3, nieuw3) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $waardes = array($_POST['subject'],$_POST['onderwerp1'],$_POST['nieuw1'],$_POST['onderwerp2'],$_POST['nieuw2'],$_POST['onderwerp3'],$_POST['nieuw3']);

    $mail = "SELECT * FROM test_mail";
    // mail sturen met link
        /////////////////////////////           
        // PHPMAILER
        /////////////////////////////
        require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->Host = "mailout.one.com";
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->setFrom('no-reply@chirojongenslennik.be', 'Chirojongens Lennik');
        $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@chirojongenslennik.be', 'Chirojongens Lennik');
        $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $htmlbericht = file_get_contents('mailtemplates/index.html');$htmlbericht = str_replace('%naam%',$mail['naam'],$htmlbericht);
        $htmlbericht = str_replace('%onderwerp1%',$_POST['onderwerp1'],$htmlbericht);
        $htmlbericht = str_replace('%nieuw1%',$_POST['nieuw1'],$htmlbericht);
        $htmlbericht = str_replace('%onderwerp2%',$_POST['onderwerp2'],$htmlbericht);
        $htmlbericht = str_replace('%nieuw2%',$_POST['nieuw2'],$htmlbericht);
        $htmlbericht = str_replace('%onderwerp3%',$_POST['onderwerp3'],$htmlbericht);
        $htmlbericht = str_replace('%nieuw3%',$_POST['nieuw3'],$htmlbericht);
        $htmlbericht = str_replace('%aandacht%',$_POST['aandacht'],$htmlbericht);;
        $mail->msgHTML($htmlbericht);
        $mail->AltBody = 'Gelieve een emailclient te gebruiken die html ondersteunt...';
        $mail->send();
    // in db steken
    Db::execute($sql,$waardes);
}?>
```

Comment: Is the mail content going to be the same for every user?

Comment: Look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer. It's much more efficient than what you have here.

Comment: No, just the %naam% is different.

Comment: I have found a solution for my problem. You can do it with a foreach :)